# Why can't boot this process at launch?

Tags: init-script, init

I have two scripts `/etc/init.d/puma_a.sh` and `/etc/init.d/puma_b.sh` with identical configs. I try to set both boot like this, but one of them doesn't load on boot. If I manually launch it from console it works. Any idea?

```
root@site:~# update-rc.d puma_a.sh defaults 98
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/puma_a.sh ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K98puma_a.sh -> ../init.d/puma_a.sh
   /etc/rc1.d/K98puma_a.sh -> ../init.d/puma_a.sh
   /etc/rc6.d/K98puma_a.sh -> ../init.d/puma_a.sh
   /etc/rc2.d/S98puma_a.sh -> ../init.d/puma_a.sh
   /etc/rc3.d/S98puma_a.sh -> ../init.d/puma_a.sh
   /etc/rc4.d/S98puma_a.sh -> ../init.d/puma_a.sh
   /etc/rc5.d/S98puma_a.sh -> ../init.d/puma_a.sh
```

`/etc/init.d/puma_a.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh


### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:   pumacontrol
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:  $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description: Puma web server 
### END INIT INFO

# Simple move this file into /etc/init.d/pumacontrol.sh
# Also make sure you `chmod +x pumacontrol.sh`.

# If you need to start puma at boot time run this in debian/ubuntu: update-rc.d pumacontrol.sh defaults
# It will create some links to execute /etc/init.d/pumacontrol.sh start at the begining

# I use this in a system where the rails app is running by a normal user,  where puma is 
# configured in PUMA_CONFIG_FILE. In PUMA_CONFIG_FILE is stated to create a pid file with the PID of 
# puma in the PUMA_PID_FILE file. The socket where nginx is redirecting the web traffic and puma is 
# listening is PUMA_SOCKET

# You need to specify a location for the PUMA_CONFIG_FILE


# /etc/init.d/puma_a.sh
PUMA_CONFIG_FILE=/var/www/site_a.com/current/config/puma.rb # WRITE HERE PUMA CONFIG FILE LOCATION
# strip out quotes, remove comments, initial spaces, and get only the filename
# if desired write here the path to the desired file for example:
# PUMA_PID_FILE=/path/foo.pid
PUMA_PID_FILE=/var/run/site_a.pid
PUMA_SOCKET=/var/run/site_a.sock
WORKING_DIR=/var/www/site_a.com/current
if [ $1 -a $2 ] ; then # If passed 2 params the second one should be the puma config file
  PUMA_CONFIG_FILE=$2
fi
PUMA_CONFIGFILE_OWNER=`ls -l $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE |cut -d' ' -f3`

#------------------------ checkings -------------------------------------
if [ ! -r $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE ] ; then # if not readable
  echo "File $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE not found or not readable"
  echo "You should write in pumacontrol.sh the location of your config/puma.rb"
  echo "or run this script like this 'pumacontrol.sh start /path/railsapp/config/puma.rb'"
  exit 1
fi
if [ -z $PUMA_PID_FILE ] ; then # if empty string
  echo "pidfile option in $PUMA_PID_FILE not found. You should write something like"
  echo 'pidfile "/path/puma.pid"'
  exit 1
fi
if [ -z $PUMA_SOCKET ] ; then # if empty string
  echo "bind option in $PUMA_SOCKET not found. You should write something like"
  echo 'bind "unix://path/railsAppName.sock"'
  exit 1
fi
if [ -z $WORKING_DIR ] ; then # if empty string
  echo "directory option in $WORKING_DIR not found. You should write something like"
  echo "directory '/path/yourRailsAppRootDir/'"
  exit 1
fi


#------------------------ functions -------------------------------------
# check if puma process is running
puma_is_running() {
  if [ -S $PUMA_SOCKET ] ; then # if file exist and its a socket
    if [ -r $PUMA_PID_FILE ] ; then # if file exist and readable
      if cat $PUMA_PID_FILE | xargs pgrep -P > /dev/null ; then
        return 0
      else
        echo "No puma process found"
      fi
    else
      echo "No puma pid file found"
    fi
  else
    echo "No puma socket found"
  fi

  return 1
}

#------------------------ script -------------------------------------
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting puma..."
      if [ -e $PUMA_SOCKET  ] ; then # if socket exists
        rm -f $PUMA_SOCKET
        echo "removed $PUMA_SOCKET"
      fi
      # Exec puma as the owner, so we need to be either root or the real owner"*
      if [ `whoami` = $PUMA_CONFIGFILE_OWNER ] # owner
      then
        /bin/bash --login -c "(cd $WORKING_DIR && bundle exec puma -C $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE)" 2>&1 >> /var/log/site_a.log
      elif [ `whoami` = root ] # root
      then
        su -l $PUMA_CONFIGFILE_OWNER -c "(cd $WORKING_DIR && bundle exec puma -C $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE)"
      else # error
        echo "you should be root or the owner of the file to have the gemset ready to start the rails stack"
      fi

    echo "done"
    ;;

  stop)
      if [ -e $PUMA_PID_FILE ] ; then # if pid file exists
        echo "Stopping puma..."
        /bin/bash --login -c " kill -s SIGTERM `cat $PUMA_PID_FILE` "
        echo "Killed puma PID `cat $PUMA_PID_FILE`"
        rm -f $PUMA_PID_FILE
        echo "removed $PUMA_PID_FILE"
      fi
      if [ -e $PUMA_SOCKET ] ; then # if socket exists
        rm -f $PUMA_SOCKET
        echo "removed  $PUMA_SOCKET"
      fi
    echo "done"
    ;;

  restart)
    if puma_is_running ; then
      echo "Hot-restarting puma..."
      if [ -e $PUMA_PID_FILE ] ; then
        /bin/bash --login -c " kill -s SIGUSR2 `cat $PUMA_PID_FILE` "
        echo "Killed puma PID `cat $PUMA_PID_FILE`"
      fi
      echo "Doublechecking the process restart..."
      sleep 5
      if puma_is_running ; then
        echo "done"
        exit 0
      else
        echo "Puma restart failed :/"
        exit 1 # return error
      fi
    fi

    echo "Trying cold reboot"
    $0 start
    ;;

  status)
    if puma_is_running ; then
      echo "puma is running"
      exit 0
    else
      echo "puma is not running"
      exit 1 # return error
    fi

    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: script/puma.sh {start|stop|restart|status}" >&2
    ;;
esac
```

and

```
ls -l /etc/init.d/puma
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4995 Sep 19 20:26 puma_a.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4985 Sep 19 19:21 puma_b.sh
```

**Update:** By looking into the logs I can see puma is unable to launch. Its weird because when I do `/etc/init.d/puma_a.sh start` manually it works.

```
[1791] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[1791] * Version 2.5.1, codename: Astronaut Shoelaces
[1791] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 32
[1791] * Environment: production
[1791] * Process workers: 6
[1791] * Preloading application
[1791] ! Unable to load application
```

**Update 2**: Result of `diff puma_{a,b}.sh`

```
93c93
<         /bin/bash --login -c "(cd $WORKING_DIR && bundle exec puma -C $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE)" 2>&1 >> /var/log/site_a.log
---
>         /bin/bash --login -c "(cd $WORKING_DIR && bundle exec puma -C $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE)" 2>&1 >> /var/log/site_b.log
96c96
<         su -l $PUMA_CONFIGFILE_OWNER -c "(cd $WORKING_DIR && bundle exec puma -C $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE)" 2>&1 >> /var/log/site_a.log
---
>         su -l $PUMA_CONFIGFILE_OWNER -c "(cd $WORKING_DIR && bundle exec puma -C $PUMA_CONFIG_FILE)"
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/init.d/puma_a.sh` and the output of `ls -l /etc/init.d/puma*` to your question?

Comment: @Martin von Wittich Please see updated question.

Comment: I can see your scripts expecting a second user argument ...
Do you run it with this second argument? or just with start/stop?

Comment: just start/stop. Its weird because on of them launch automatically and the other dont. Both are the same. To launch it manually I just run `/etc/init.d/puma_a.sh start`

Comment: Just a second ...
You have both of them in the boot sequence, and both launch the same daemon?
Are you sure you can run multiple instance of this daemon?
Basically at boot, both of them will be started. Are you able to start both of them, without stopping the other and having both running together?

Comment: I tried removing the init launch for `puma_b.sh` using `update-rc.d -f puma_b.sh remove`, reboot and `puma_a.sh` still not launching. If I launch `puma_a.sh` manually they both work.

Comment: You will probably have to find a way to make this Puma server print a more detailed error message, because `Unable to load application` isn't very specific.

Comment: Feel the same. Tried to redirect stdout from Puma but the file is empty.

Comment: Does it require network access?

Comment: Using `stdout_redirect "/var/log/puma.site_a.access.log", "/var/log/puma.site.error.log"` on puma config file.

Comment: @Bichoy what do you mean? Its using a local unix socket.

Comment: If it needs to connect to other machines or something (as it appears to be run on a cluster), perhaps at the time of boot it is being started, the network interface is not up yet ...
This can be the case if the interface is managed by network manager ...

Comment: the cluster is simply to launch several Puma workers on same machine.

Comment: How "identical" are `puma_a.sh` and `puma_b.sh`? What does `diff puma_{a,b}.sh` produce?

Comment: @JosephR. Please see updated question with diff results.

Comment: Three obvious questions that come to mind: 1- Did you remove the extra redirection in `puma_a.sh` after the `su` statement and try if `puma_a` would launch at startup? 2- Did you check `/var/log/site_a.txt`? 3- Why do you have `2>&1` before `>> /var/log/site_a.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the script executable in the first place.

```
chmod +x puma_a.sh
```

Putting a script in the boot sequence without execution permission will be ignored.

Comment: Already did, without that I could not launch it manually.